# How to move part of a row to a new row in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of many columns, while in the middle of each row, the columns start over.

For example, my columns appear like this:

```
App_Name  Price  Rating   App_name   Price   Rating
Netflix   5.00$    4.1    Netflix     2.00$   3.1
```

I would like to split this row between Rating and App_Name to form a new row to have:

```
App_Name   Price   Rating
 Netflix    5.00$   4.1
 Netflix    2.00$   3.1
```

What do I need to use to make this happen?

Comment: It doesn't seem that you imported it as a ```pandas``` dataframe, it would have added a suffix at the end of the duplicated columns.

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.title()    
df=(df.T.set_index(df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).cumcount(),append=True)
      .unstack().T.reset_index(drop=True))
```

**OR**

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.title() 
df=df.T.reset_index()
df[1]=df.groupby('index').cumcount()
df=df.pivot('index',1,0).T.rename_axis(columns=None,index=None)
```

output of `df`:

```
   App_Name     Price   Rating
0   Netflix     5.00$   4.1
1   Netflix     2.00$   3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({i: df[i].values.T.ravel() for i in set(df.columns)})
```

But be sure that your columns have the same name (i.e.: `App_Name` and `App_name`)

Answer (score 0):

If really your dataframe only needs to be split in two, you can use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on the two halves:

```
mid = len(df.columns)//2
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :mid],
                df.iloc[:, mid:].rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns[mid:],
                                                         df.columns[:mid])))
               ], ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
  App_Name  Price  Rating
0  Netflix  5.00$     4.1
1  Netflix  2.00$     3.1
```

*NB. this will keep the names of the first half of the original dataframe. If you are sure both halves have the same column names, you can remove the `.rename(…)` part*